# Computing MMSE and conditional expectation

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, expectation, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have three independent, zero mean, finite variance random variables $V,W,Z$ and where $W,Z$ are Gaussian random variables. 
These random variables form a new random variable $Y$
\begin{align*}
Y=V+W+Z
\end{align*}

I want to compute the following quantity
\begin{align*}
E[W(V-E[V|Y])]
\end{align*}

I have the following conjecture
\begin{align*}
&E[W(V-E[V|Y])]\\
&=E[(W+Z)(V-E[V|Y])]\sqrt{\frac{E[W^2]}{E[W^2]+E[Z^2]}} \text{ Problematic step}\\
&=E[(Y-V)(V-E[V|Y])]\sqrt{\frac{E[W^2]}{E[W^2]+E[Z^2]}}\\
&=E[(V-E[V|Y])^2]\sqrt{\frac{E[W^2]}{E[W^2]+E[Z^2]}} \text{ by orthogonality principle}
\end{align*}

In the  'Problematic Step' I am not completly sure I can add $Z$ and normalize. Is that step fine if yes how to argue it?

For example, in the case when $V$ is Gaussian this is easy to verify.

**{Possible Approach:}**

I was thinking of using the following approach:

In really we have to show that 
\begin{align*}
E[W E[V|Y]]= \alpha E[(W+Z) E[V|Y]]
\end{align*}
where the conjecture is that $\alpha=\sqrt{\frac{E[W^2]}{E[W^2]+E[Z^2]}}$.

So, we really have to show that
\begin{align*}
&\int \int w E[V|Y=y] f_{W,Y} (w,y) dw dy\\
&= \alpha  \int \int \int (w+z) E[V|Y=y] f_{Z,W,Y} (z,w,y) dw dy dz\\
&= \alpha   \int \int s E[V|Y=y] f_{Y,S} (y,s) ds dy
\end{align*}
where $S=W+Z$.

but how to show the last step?? The good thing is that $S=W+Z$ is Gaussian so maybe it will make things easeir.

Thank you